# How to resolve "@Url cannot be used with @PUT URL (parameter #1)"

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to use `@PUT` and `@Url` together, but it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`

---

#### Edit

```
@PUT 
fun editPost(
    @Url() url: String = "xxxx/threads/{tid}",
    @Path("tid") postId:Long,
    @Body x: X
)
```

Comment: can you add your code

Comment: There is no context to this question

Comment: @PUT
    fun editPost(@Url() url: String = "xxxx/threads/{tid}",@Path("tid") postId:Long,@Body x: X)

Comment: Taht is my code

Comment: @Zero Ok, I have edited your answer and upvoted it because that is a valuable question which people will need an answer too. Make sure to format your questions well and be specific. As Milan as mentioned, always add your code if you can. I am now providing an explanation as to why you had this issue, take a look at my answer

Comment: @Zero How did you solved this problem ? Facing same issue. Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on the assumption of you using Retrofit Library to make a API call. If that's not the case, my apologies and let me know so I can modify/remove the answer.

From what I've researched, you've probably implemented your interface method like the following:

```
@PUT("")
Call...
```

With this call, you should encounter ***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameteras*** you've not provided the addition parameter which is needed to complete the API call.
Therefore, you must keep the base URL in the mainActivity where you'll be making the call and route of the API within the bracket of the interface

```
@PUT("user/id")
```

or if you want to keep it blank as original, you must use `@PUT(".")` as this will declare that your final URL is the same as the Base URL provided in the mainActivity.

Answer (score -1):

### You were very close...

```
@PUT("xxxx/threads/{tid}"
fun editPost(
    @Path("tid") postId: Long,
    @Body x: X
)
```

Comment: @Zero this will solve your issue - let me know if you have any questions